# How can we grab Favicon from any site? if it was not in view source code

Tags: html, css, favicon

I want to grab Favicon from some site but it's not visible via saving file or in view source code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is visible on the source code, but you will have to do some searching because may the favicon be "hidden" inside some property of a .XML called browserconfig.xml . So, open the source of your desired site and search (many times the reference to the image file is done without file extension (.ICO or .GIF, for example). Yes, can be a heavy work. Best luck.

Comment: Yes!! but in some cases we observed it can't even there.

Comment: If there is a favicon showed, the browser was instructed to exhibit it and it is almost always an external image file loaded from the server. It's just the case of discovering how is the site pointing to that file. There is only one exception to that (and that's why "almost always"): newer Opera and Firefox browsers support .SVG files as favicons, and, as you already know, an SVG file can be made "on fly", realtime, build by coding - so dismissing the need for an external image file. Thanks for recognizing.

Comment: This answer is mostly wrong. Favicon is never declared via CSS files and very rarely as JavaScript. Most of the time is is present in the head section of.the HTML page itself. Please edit your answer or remove it.

Answer (score -1):

We can grab the favicon of any website by using below site.

- https://icons.better-idea.org/

Comment: Voting down to suspend your answer. It seems you are the owner of this url's site and want some merchandising on that. Besides it, your answer is off-topic by various itens defined in StackOverflow Help, yet does not contribute to explain what is in focus on the original question. This is not a place to recommend solutions, softwares and websites. Could flag it too.